# Внедрение глифов в svg

Tags: svg, шрифты

Есть такой svg

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<svg width="40" height="40" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <defs>
    <font id="antoniobold" horiz-adv-x="976">
      <font-face font-family="antonio-bold" units-per-em="2048" ascent="1638" descent="-410"/>
      <missing-glyph horiz-adv-x="367"/>
      <glyph unicode="6" horiz-adv-x="951" d="M370 1019q63 84 219 84t224 -125t68 -398v-97q0 -254 -80 -379t-302 -125q-274 1 -351 209q-46 125 -46 339v723q0 382 176 482q86 48 224 49q179 0 260.5 -101.5t82.5 -343.5v-91h-250v36q0 159 -18 213t-90 54t-94.5 -58t-22.5 -220v-251zM499 212q72 0 97.5 47 t25.5 175v167q0 148 -25.5 209t-86.5 61t-97.5 -27.5t-42.5 -66.5v-318q0 -131 28.5 -189t100.5 -58z"/>
    </font>
  </defs>
  <circle cx="20" cy="20" r="18" fill="#48CD3F"/>
  <text font-family="antonio-bold" x="20" y="20" text-anchor="middle" font-size="14" dominant-baseline="middle" fill="black">6</text>
</svg>
```

Вопрос: почему используется стандартный шрифт, а не определенный мной?

Comment: На сервере? Возможно шрифта такого нет?

Comment: @StanislavHmelevsky Я его определяю сам в этом же файле. Шрифт с одним глифом

Comment: Судя по [мануалу](http://nimbupani.com/about-fonts-in-svg.html) юзать рекомендуют стандартные шрифты, т.к. это легче. А если использовать внешние, то использовать @font-face css объявление, для подключения. P.S. У меня  вот например такого шрифта нет, по этому выглядит стандартно. Из этого вывод, если на сервере подключайте шрифты. Либо заворачивайте их в проект.

Comment: Если svg с импортом шрифтов подключить в другой svg через `<image href="..."` то шрифты не импортируются https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/990086/%D0%98%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82-%D1%88%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%84%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%B2-%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-svg

Comment: Попробуйте в CSS или в HTML подключить. В мануале описано.

Comment: @StanislavHmelevsky Еще раз - в самом svg все подключается и корректно отображается. Но если этот svg подключить в другой svg, то все импорты идут лесом. Перечитайте вопрос в комментарии